# How to find default value/change search.allow_expensive_queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if there is a way to see default value of Elasticsearch param `search.allow_expensive_queries` (e.g. in Kibana) and change it if necessary via console of DevTools or `environment` section of `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `search.allow_expensive_queries` value is set to true, if you want to prevent users from running certain types of expensive queries, then you can add this setting to the cluster:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "search.allow_expensive_queries": "false"
  }
}
```

To check if the setting is set or not in the cluster you can call this API:

```
GET /_cluster/settings
```

and result should be like below if it is set to false or true:

```
{
  "persistent" : { },
  "transient" : {
    "search" : {
      "allow_expensive_queries" : ["false" or "true"]
    }
  }
}
```

If no information is retuned by the API in `transient` part it means that the value is set to `true`.